# Update input values multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, nouislider

I've been using nouislider https://refreshless.com/nouislider/. The slider must handle with two values. This one works but i need it multiple times (about 10 sliders). Each slider must have his own 2 inputs (like the fiddle below)

How can i use this for more than one slider:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
            start: [1, 10000000],
      range: {
        'min': 1,
        'max': 1000000
      },
      connect: true,
      step: 1
});

var valueInputMin = document.getElementById('valueInputMin');
var valueInputMax= document.getElementById('valueInputMax');
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    if ( handle ) {
        valueInputMax.value = values[handle];
    } else {
        valueInputMin.value = values[handle];
    }
});

valueInputMin.addEventListener('change', function(){
    slider.noUiSlider.set([this.value,null]);
});
valueInputMax.addEventListener('change', function(){
    slider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cprixi/haqjk8vb/6/

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle and explain your requirement in detail?

Comment: Please give more details about what you want to achieve ? if you want to use slider more times then 
var slider1 = document.getElementById('slider1');
var slider2= document.getElementById('slider2');
............
var sliderN = document.getElementById('sliderN');

Comment: there's fiddle now. I need to do this multiple times and every slider need 2 inputs like in the fiddle. Is it possible to so this with getElementsByClassName?

Comment: update the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cprixi/haqjk8vb/11/ but isn't there a better way to do this with less code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code with your change if required

```
var sliders= [];
var valueInputMin = [];
var valueInputMax=  [];

// change i to as many html element you have
// you can also create and a html in the same loop
for(var i=1; i<=2; i++){
    sliders[i] = document.getElementById('slider'+i);

  noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
        start: [0, 100],
        range: {
          'min': 0,
          'max': 100
        },
        connect: true,
        step: 1
  });

  valueInputMin[i] =    document.getElementById('valueInputMin'+i);
  valueInputMax[i] = document.getElementById('valueInputMax'+i);

   sliders[i].noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle)        {
   var id = this.target.id;
   var index = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
    if ( handle ) {
      valueInputMax[index].value = values[handle];

    } else {
      valueInputMin[index].value = values[handle];
    } 
});

 valueInputMin[i].addEventListener('change', function(event){
  // index can be found with better other ways
   var id = this.target.id;
   var index = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
   sliders[index].noUiSlider.set([this.value,null]); 
    });


  valueInputMax[i].addEventListener('change', function(event){
   // index can be found with better other ways
    var id = this.target.id;
    var index = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
     sliders[index].noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]); 
  });
}
```

Core Concept to this is to use arrays to hold the objects.You can also create html elements and append it to the dom in the same loop just to avoid statically defining html before hand.Then you just need to change max value of i in loop to get as many sliders you want.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sksethi25/f3qs08db/6/